# 「一生懸命」と「一所懸命」の使い方は同じでしょうか？

Tags: word-choice, usage

「一生懸命」と「一所懸命」 の使い方は同じでしょうか？意味も同じでしょうか？

Answer (score 5):

Both 一所懸命 and 一生懸命 are currently in parallel use to mean *endeavoring with all one’s might*. The former literally means *to risk one’s life “at a place” for achieving something*, while the latter means *to do something at “a risk of one’s life” for achieving something*.

Though 一所懸命 and 一生懸命 are used in the same meaning, 一生懸命 was derived from 一所懸命, which originally meant that 武士 – Samurai – in ancient times survived by desperately defending their fief given or assigned by the Mikado or Shogun against invaders.

Both words are used interchangeably today because they sound almost the same and the concept of risking life on defending one's territory is no longer relevant to the people of today.